# Noisy / Grainy photos on iPhone 12 series when setting exposure duration and ISO

Tags: ios, objective-c, image-processing, avfoundation

When capturing photos of with the iPhone 12 series with custom exposure durations and ISO, the results contain a significant amount of noise compared to the iPhone 11 & X series.

Setting a custom exposure duration & ISO can be done in one of the following ways:

- capturing using bracketed settings:

```
AVCapturePhotoOutput *photoOutput;
// ...
NSArray *bracketedSettings = @[[AVCaptureManualExposureBracketedStillImageSettings manualExposureSettingsWithExposureDuration:CMTimeMake(1, 7000) ISO:50]];
AVCapturePhotoBracketSettings *photoSettings = [AVCapturePhotoBracketSettings photoBracketSettingsWithRawPixelFormatType:0 processedFormat:nil bracketedSettings:bracketedSettings];
[photoOutput capturePhotoWithSettings:photoSettings delegate:self];
```

- setting the exposure & ISO on the capture device:

```
AVCaptureDevice *captureDevice;
// ...
[captureDevice setExposureModeCustomWithDuration:CMTimeMake(1, 7000) ISO:50 completionHandler:^(CMTime syncTime) {
   // capture photo
}];
```

Any of these methods will result in noisier photos on iPhone 12 series. Using the ultra wide angle lens will achieve the worst results.

[This](https://github.com/abouariu-nodalview/ShutterSpeed) example project captures 9 photos using bracketed settings with different exposure durations (1/7200, 1/1600, 1/400, 1/100, 1/24, 1/12, 1/6, 1/3, 1/2) and ISO set to 50. The noisiest are 1/100 and 1/24:

iPhone 11 Pro 1/24
[image]

iPhone 12 Pro 1/24
[image: iPhone 12 Pro]

Things that I've tried so far:

- capturing in RAW format, compressed format (JPEG/HEIC) and 3 uncompressed supported formats (875704422, 875704438, 1111970369).
- setting the photo settings quality to `AVCapturePhotoQualityPrioritizationSpeed`, `AVCapturePhotoQualityPrioritizationBalanced` and `AVCapturePhotoQualityPrioritizationQuality` (always set to speed when setting the exposure duration & ISO on the capture device, otherwise the set shutter speed & ISO may be ignored as per [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/1624646-setexposuremodecustomwithduratio) - online documentation doesn't specify this, but the XCode documentation does)
- applying noise reduction `CIFilter`, but it barely improves the results.
- delaying capturing by 0.5-1 seconds when setting the exposure mode & ISO on the capture device, since I've noticed that starting capturing as soon as the completion handler is called will result in images that don't seem to respect the set parameters.
- writing the images on disk in any of the following ways:

  - `NSData writeToFile:atomically:` for photo.fileDataRepresentation
  - Create a `UIImage` from photo.fileDataRepresentation and write it with different compression levels with `UIImageJPEGRepresentation(UIImage *, CGFloat)`
  - Create a `CIImage` and write it with different compression levels with `CIContext writeJPEGRepresentationOfImage:toURL:colorSpace:options:error:`

How can the noise issue be fixed?

Comment: Are you saying that running the same code, to capture photos, on an iPhone 12 series, the results are noisier than when running the same code on an iPhone 11 & X series? Also just curious, if you capture the photo with the native photo app, is the result the same or better?

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the coding side but rather a hardware limitation.

The ISO  refers to the sensitivity of the camera's sensor (CMOS) to capture the light. Higher the ISO setting, the higher the voltage running in the CMOS chip which captures light, amplifies them and generates a digital signal which we get as a RAW image or some processed image.

While working with high voltage, there will be the noise as a byproduct. This is like increasing the audio volume of a faint sound clip, where we will hear more noise than what we hear before increasing the volume.

Generally, some clever denoising algorithms can help to digitally reduce the noise, but the image quality may get degraded or appear artificial. Here is an article which covers some of them, if you are interested:
https://towardsdatascience.com/introduction-to-image-denoising-3e269f176483

According to the article, probably these noise are considered Gaussian Noise and restoration involves estimation of the original image. It says,

> Gaussian filter is a linear filter that can effectively suppress noise and smooth the image. Its working principle is similar to that of an average filter, and both take the average value of the pixels in the filter window as the output.

The photo will appear slightly blur though.

Comment: This is far from being a technical answer to my question. Indeed, high ISO means high noise. The ISO in the example above is set to 50, while the min supported ISO for the standard lens is 33 and the min supported ISO for the ultra wide angle lens is 25. I've already tried Apple's noise reduction filter which slightly improves the results.

Comment: “probably these noise are considered Gaussian Noise”: This is the wrong noise model for a CMOS camera. The noise is typically much more complex as a lot of processing happens internally even before you obtain the “raw” image. Before the processing, noise is dominated by thermal and electronic noise, which don’t usually add up to a Gaussian distribution, especially in the cases where there is little signal and therefore lots of noise. The processing means that the distribution is not the same for each pixel, which makes the modeling even harder.

Comment: @Dog I didn't know that you set the ISO to fixed 50. You have recently made a modification in the question to highlight that part which is very appreciated. Are you saying that the noisiest are the 1/100 and 1/24 exposure settings? Does that mean other longer exposures don't create much grains?

Comment: @CrisLuengo thanks for your clarification. I am just referring to some of the excerpts from the article.

Comment: @KiranShakya the last edit was made on March 26, long before your answer. The high exposures are still noisy, but not as much. The project on Github also shows the results of the capturing.